# SQL : Select statement order by other table

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to select a column but with diferent order :

i have 2 table :

table_name:

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
| 1    |    Sindra |
| 2    |    Auli   |
| 3    |    Brian  |
| 4    |    Bina   |
| 5    |    zian   |
| 6    |    Bri    |
| 7    |    Andre  |
+------+-----------+
```

table_temp, id_temp_name foreign key of id(table_name) :

```
+------+--------------+
| id   | id_temp_name |
+------+--------------+
| 1    |    1         |
| 2    |    3         |
| 3    |    4         |
| 4    |    2         |
+------+--------------+
```

with this query :

```
  SELECT  table_name.id,table_name.name 
  FROM table_name JOIN table_temp ON table_name.id= table_temp.id_temp_name 
  ORDER BY table_temp.id_temp_name
```

i was looking for result that exactly same with id_temp_name order , but it showing value that not in to table_temp to order by asc ,so the result will be :

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
| 1    |    Sindra |
| 3    |    Brian  |
| 4    |    Bina   |
| 2    |    Auli   |
| 7    |    Andre  |
| 6    |    Bri    |
| 5    |    zian   |
+------+-----------+
```

thanks for any advice, .

Comment: use Left join and order id_temp_name

Comment: use current nomenclature in your question as per your tables in your query or use alias

Comment: sorry i was edited my query, :). please see again.

Comment: @walk.this_way what if 7, 6 ,5 comes before 1, 3, 4, 2 ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan that exactly the problem, 7,6,5 comes before 1,3,4,2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I tried so many times, and I could find queries that displays result exactly same as you needed. But work has to be done in two steps with an assumption that `id`s can't be negative.

Step-1: Create a valuable:

```
mysql> SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name) * 2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Step-2: A nested Query that use above variable:

```
mysql> SELECT  a.id,
    ->         a.name
    -> FROM (
    -> SELECT  t.id as `id`,
    ->         t.name as `name`, 
    ->         IF(t2.id, t2.id, @max_id := @max_id - 1)  as `id2`
    -> FROM table_name t
    -> LEFT OUTER JOIN table_temp t2
    ->   ON t.id= t2.id_temp_name
    -> GROUP BY t.id
    -> ORDER BY CASE  WHEN t2.id  THEN t2.id
    ->          ELSE  -t.id  END
    -> ) as a
    -> ORDER BY a.id2;
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | Sindra |
|    3 | Brian  |
|    4 | Bina   |
|    2 | Auli   |
|    7 | Andre  |
|    6 | Bri    |
|    5 | zian   |
+------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Check it working @ [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad625/1).

The logic is very simple, I used a bit math, and added new `Id` on the fly in inner SQL query. I used `max_id` variable twice of max value of present id in table_name purpose fully because I am generating `id` that should be grater than max and in decreasing order (I did subtraction).

Give it a try!!

Comment: thanks :D, i was looking for this more than 4 hours this day . .

will it work if i use that query in sqlite ?

Comment: @walk.this_way But doesn't prime-minister-of-india's answer work?

Comment: it works , but sorting is not right , result : 4,3,2,1,7,6,5 and i can't find any way to modified it to make it work..

will it work in sqlite ??

btw thanks so much :D

Comment: @walk.this_way Yes I tried [his Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad625/3). I tried to modify his query that is faster. Btw thanks to you to I never tried this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**AFTER EDIT 1:**

You can proceed to [this_way](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3146681/walk-this-way)

```
SELECT  tgejala.id_gejala,tgejala.nama_gejala 
FROM tgejala 
LEFT JOIN ttemp ON tgejala.id_gejala= ttemp.idtemp_gejala 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ttemp.id_temp is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

**EDIT 2:**
Ok then see the below this would work

```
SELECT  tgejala.id_gejala,tgejala.nama_gejala 
FROM tgejala 
LEFT JOIN ttemp ON tgejala.id_gejala= ttemp.idtemp_gejala 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ttemp.id_temp is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, table_name.id desc
```

This will give you the following result

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
| 1    |    Sindra |
| 3    |    Brian  |
| 4    |    Bina   |
| 2    |    Auli   |
| 7    |    Andre  |
| 6    |    Bri    |
| 5    |    zian   |
+------+-----------+
```

Comment: the result is fine, but value name that not in table_temp is list first, how to list it to the last

Comment: thanks @prime_minister_of_india, the result fine but its not list like im looking for, it sort ascending, im looking for that first sorting is tgejala.nama_gejala from table ttemp.idtemp_gejala, and after that srting tgejala.nama_gejala that not in ttemp.idtemp_gejala and sorting it by ascending.. thanks for any advice ,, sorry for my english :(

Comment: @walk.this_way If you really could explain what really you want then and only then we could help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need a `left outer join` so you keep all the records in the first table:

```
  SELECT  tn.id, tn.name 
  FROM table_name tn LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table_temp tt
       ON tn.id= tt.id_temp_name 
  ORDER BY (tt.id_temp_name is not null) desc,
           tt.id_temp_name ;
```

The first condition in the `order by` is to ensure that the missing values go last, regardless of the order of the second clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Select a.id_temp_name, b.name
from table_temp a, table_name b
where a.id = b.id 
order by a.id_temp_name;
```

See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem in SQL Server:

```
SELECT  table_name.id,table_name.name
FROM table_name as table_name
LEFT JOIN table_temp as table_temp ON table_name.id= table_temp.id_temp_name 
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN cast(table_temp.id as varchar) IS NOT NULL 
        THEN cast(table_temp.id as varchar) 
    ELSE table_name.name  END asc
```